# from Azure AD list users who are groupmember of two group at same time

Tags: powershell

I am trying to list users who belong to two similar groups at same time from Azure AD:

```bash
$IDs = Get-AzADGroupMember -GroupObjectId | Select-Object ID
foreach ($ID in $IDs) {
    Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $ID |
        Select-Object displayname |
        Where-Object { $_.displayname -like 'ABC*' }
}
```

But got this error:

```
Get-AzureADUserMembership : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
At line:3 char:1
+ Get-AzureADUserMembership  -ObjectId $ID  | select displayname | ?{($ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADUserMembership], JsonReaderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetUserMemberships
```

Comment: "got error here" in your question, where? what error?

Comment: please edit your question and add the error there

Comment: change `$IDs = Get-AzADGroupMember -GroupObjectId | Select-Object ID` to `$IDs = (Get-AzADGroupMember -GroupObjectId $theGroupGuid).ID` and you should be good to go ;)